# Change theme color from server

Tags: android, android-theme

Can I change theme color from remote server? I want to change color theme from server like colorPrimary, colorPrimaryDark and accentColor. I know that resources are constant in android and can't change its value runtime.
If there is any way to change theme color runtime, please suggest me.

Answer (score -1):

Try following line in your code.

```
setTheme(android.R.style.custom_theme);
```

Comment: I think you did not understand my question. When i choose color from server my app theme color should be changed on that particular color.

Comment: @shaileshojha ok, got it sorry i will  let you know.